# Grails - Fails to submit base64 img

Tags: ajax, grails, base64

I need to make ajax submit to submit some data include a base64 string of the image, which is render from canvas.

When submit I look in the network panel of Chrome inspector and everything look fine, in "form data" it list all the data that I want to submit.

But in Grails I cannot get the data, there is nothing in the `params`, just the controller name and action name. Thus everything I get with simple `params.dataName` is null.

I guess there is something with the size of the post request, but I'm not so sure as I have done this before without ajax.

This is my code for upload with jquery ajax:

```
var imgBase64String = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
imgBase64String = imgBase64String .replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
var submitData = $(form).serializeArray();
submitData.push({name: "webImage", value: imgBase64String })
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '${createLink(action: 'myAction')}',
    data: submitData,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){//Success code},
});
```

**UPDATE**

My code on the server side, it fails at the simple step to retrieve `params` data:

```
def myAction= {
        def paramData = params
        log.info "paramData: " + paramData

        def url = params.url
        def email = params.email
        def webImage = params.webImage
        log.info "param: url = " + url
        log.info "param: email = " + email
        log.info "param: webImage = " + webImage

        //Other implement code      
}
```

And the output:

```
2012-10-08 16:31:28,988 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  myController  - paramData: [action:myAction, controller:myController]
2012-10-08 16:31:28,989 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  myController  - param: url = null
2012-10-08 16:31:28,989 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  myController  - param: email = null
2012-10-08 16:31:28,989 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  myController  - param: webImage = null
```

The size of the base64 image I'm trying to submit is 1998720, don't know if this matter.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply pass `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` into the `data` field in the `$.ajax()` method. Also use `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`. So your code should look like this in the js file:

```
$.post('/image/getCanvasImage',  //this is your url
  {
    img : canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
    email : email
  }, function(data){
      //whatever you wanna do with the returned data
  }
);
```

Then in your action, import `import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` package and you can write this code to save the canvas image:

```
def file = params.img.toString().substring((params.img.toString().indexOf(",")+1),params.img.toString().size())
byte[] decodedBytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(file)
def image = new File("mySavedImage.jpg")
image.setBytes(decodedBytes)
```

Should work!

Comment: Yes it should, but it's not because the `params.img` is null and even the `params.email` is also null, that's the problem I'm facing. ;(

Comment: can you post your controler's action's code? and is your gsp's action part of the same controller that has the uploading action (`myAction` in your case) - because i see in your code that you havent given a controller to your `createLink()` tag.

Comment: yes I'm sure the action is called correctly. I have updated my question with controller code.

Comment: your problem then might lie in your javascript `submitData` variable.. can you put a breakpoint and see what that variable holds before its being sent to the server?

Comment: When I inspect in the browser (debug in javascript & look at httpRequest) everything looks fine.
I think the problem is with the base64 string. When I remove base64 string from `submitData`, it works.